# Return a graph based on the number of relationships between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am experimenting with creating **multiple** relationships between nodes to represent the **importance** between two given nodes.

For example, I want to know what 'genre' of reading material is most important to Joe.

[image: Neo4j Graph of What Joe likes to read]

I want a way to match the Joe node to genre nodes only if there is some number or greater relationships between them.

So, if I want matches with 3 or more relationships, I should get a graph with **Joe** --> **Fantasy**

I know I can get this when both endpoints are defined:

```
MATCH (p:PERSON {name:'Joe'})-[r]->(g: GENRE {name:'Fantasy'}) 
RETURN count(r)
```

What I want is something like:

```
MATCH p = (p:PERSON {name:'Joe'})-[r]->()
WHERE *pair_relationship_count*(r) >= 3
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposition:

```
MATCH path = (p:PERSON {name:'Joe'})-[r]->() 
WITH collect(path) as paths, collect(r) as pair_count
WITH paths WHERE size(pair_count) >= 3 
UNWIND paths as path
RETURN path
```

But maybe it is more efficient to have one relationship with an internal count property on one relationship for each couple of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you can achieve your goal using [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/) clause:

```
MATCH path = (:PERSON {name:'Joe'})-[r]->(:GENRE {name:'Fantasy'})
WITH path, count(r) as count
WHERE count > 3
RETURN path
```

But using one relationship for each read "event" seems to be a bad approach. Maybe you should use an integer property in the relationship, then increment this property for each "read". This way you can do queries like:

```
MATCH path = (:PERSON {name:'Joe'})-[r]->(:GENRE {name:'Fantasy'})
WHERE r.count > 3
RETURN path
```

Comment: Bruno/SylvianRoussy I think you are both are correct in having a count property, and in the inefficiency of duplicate rels. It does make an issue if there are other properties that may need to be filtered. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

To get a collection of all `READS` paths for "Joe" that involve each genre that he has read at least 3 times:

```
MATCH p = (:PERSON {name:'Joe'})-[:READS]->(genre)
WITH genre, COLLECT(p) AS paths
WHERE SIZE(paths) >= 3
RETURN genre, paths;
```